# How to round a number to 10 correct decimal places in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I round values of x and g(x) to 10 decimal places?? I feel like `fprintf('%0.10', number)` does not give the desired output, does it???? My output is giving me the numbers up to 6 decimal places instead of 10:

```
 fpi1(g, 0.5, 60)
0.500000            1.951392 
1.951392            1.706095 
1.706095            1.543600 
1.543600            1.462184 
1.462184            1.430210 
1.430210            1.419396 
1.419396            1.415971 
1.415971            1.414911 
1.414911            1.414585 
1.414585            1.414485 
1.414485            1.414454 
1.414454            1.414445 
1.414445            1.414442 
1.414442            1.414441 
1.414441            1.414441 
1.414441            1.414441 
1.414441            1.414441 
1.414441            1.414441 
1.414441            1.414441 
1.414441            1.414441 
1.414441            1.414441 
1.414441            1.414441 
1.414441            1.414441
```

What is the command to fix it, i.e. to make the output to 10 decimal places? Thanks in advance!

```
%Program 1.2 Fixed-Point Iteration
%Computes approximate solution of g(x)=x
%Input: inline function g, starting guess x0, 
%       number of steps k
%Output: Approximate solution xc
function xc=fpi1(g,x0,k)
format long;
x(1)=x0;
for i=1:k
  x(i+1)=g(x(i));

  fprintf('%f            %f \n', x(i), g(x(i)));
  %printf(x(i), g(x(i)));
end
xc=x(k+1);
```

Answer (score 3):

It's `fprintf('%0.10f', number);`.  You forgot the `f` in the specifier.

```
>> number = 141421.1240981320948710948018941;
>> fprintf('%0.10f\n', number)
141421.1240981321
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`round`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/round.html) and set the number of digits to `10`:

```
Y = round(X,N);% rounds to N digits
```

Note that this only rounds the actual numbers, for displaying them you need `frpintf` as answered by @rayryeng.

Comment: Clearly you've got something better than  R2012  :-(

Comment: What version was this implemented in?

Comment: @IKavanagh In R2014b, these syntaxes were added to round to any number of decimal or significant digits and to round duration values:

Y = round(X,N)
Y = round(X,N,type)
Y = round(t)  
Y = round(t,unit)   
Older versions support only this syntax, which rounds to the nearest integer:

Y = round(X)   as per documentation

Comment: Ah, I'm still on R2014a. So I didn't write my own `roundto()` function for nothing!

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually want to round the numbers, or just round the displayed values?  Using `fprintf` only does the latter.  To round the data itself, you can do something along the lines of

```
foo = round(foo.*1000)./1000
```

Which will round to 3 places.  It's insanely stupid of Mathworks not to include a "number_of_digits" argument to `round` --  many of us just roll our own function along the lines of

```
myround(x,numdig)
x = round(x.*(10^numdig))./(10^numdig)
```

Comment: `round` actually has that functionality, see my answer and the docs.