# Range error using imagesc()

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, signals

I want apply the 2D Discrete Cosine Transform to a generated 8x8 pixel white image using the DCT matrix U and then recover and plot the image.

Calculation of the matrix U:

```
N = 8; 
k = 0:N-1; 
u = 0:N-1;
U = cos(u'*pi*(k+0.5)/N)*sqrt(2/N);
U (1,1:N) = U(1,1:N)/sqrt(2);
```

Image X:

```
X = ones(8, 8, 3, 'double');
```

DCT 2D Transform of the image X:

```
Y(:,:,1) = U*X(:,:,1)*U';
Y(:,:,2) = U*X(:,:,2)*U';
Y(:,:,3) = U*X(:,:,3)*U';
```

Recovered image:

```
Xr(:,:,1) = U'*Y(:,:,1)*U;
Xr(:,:,2) = U'*Y(:,:,2)*U;
Xr(:,:,3) = U'*Y(:,:,3)*U;
```

Now, when I try to do:

```
figure;
subplot(2, 1, 1);
imagesc(X);
axis off;
title('Original image');

subplot(2, 1, 2);
imagesc(Xr);
axis off;
title('Recovered image');
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using image
TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0

Error in imagesc (line 18)
hh = image(varargin{1},'CDataMapping','scaled');

Error in Ejercicio1_3 (line 32)
imagesc(Xr);
```

And the values of the matrix Xr is:

```
Xr(:,:,1) =

 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000


Xr(:,:,2) =

 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000


Xr(:,:,3) =

 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
 1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000    1.0000
```

Why am I getting this error when all values are in then right range? (0.0, 1.0)

Comment: Your code fails on `Y = U*X*U';` as `X` is a 3D matrix

Comment: Thank you @nirvana-msu, I've fixed the post.

Comment: Can you tell us what the result of `fprintf("%.17g\n", max(Xr(:)))` is?

Comment: Thanks @beaker. It prints: 1.0000000000000009. So, how can I trunc the value to 4 decimal digits?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32619876/how-to-round-a-number-to-10-correct-decimal-places-in-matlab for options on truncating to a certain number of decimal places. Alternatively, you can clamp the values as @nirvana-msu suggests, or divide by `max(Xr(:))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly mentioned in the comments, this is because some `Xr` values are larger than `1` due to machine precision limitations:

```
>> num2str(max(Xr(:)), 17)
ans =
1.0000000000000013
```

You can simply cap `Xr` values before plotting:

```
Xr_capped = min(Xr,1);
imagesc(Xr_capped);
```